# What exactly is computation?

Tags: terminology, computability

I know what computation is in some vague sense (it is the thing computers do), but I would like a more rigorous definition.

`Dictionary.com`'s definitions of computation, computing, calculate, and compute are circular, so it doesn't help.

`Wikipedia` defines computation to be "any type of calculation that follows a well-defined model." 
It defines calculation as "the deliberate process that transforms one or more inputs into one or more results, with variable change." But it seems this definition includes many actions as computations even though they aren't typically thought of as computation.

For example, wouldn't this entail that, say, a bomb exploding is a computation, with the input being the fuse being lighted and the output being the explosion?

So, what exactly is computation?

Comment: That's a great, classical, question.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/what-exactly-is-an-algorithm)?

Comment: @Raphael As far as I know, computation != an algorithm. Perhaps the execution of an algorithm is computation, though.

Comment: For me, "P is computable" == "There is an algorithm that solves P" (for P some problem). This may be a result from my TCS perspective, though.

Comment: @Raphael This is asking what computation is, not what it means for P to be computable.

Comment: I don't think you can separate the notions in a reasonable way.

Comment: I think every introduction to algorithm class/book has this covered.

Comment: @XiangJi As far as I know, *Introduction to Algorithms*, a very popular book on algorithms, never defines computation.

Comment: @xji this has nothing to do with algorithms and more to do with computability/automata theory

Comment: @Kelmikra a bomb exploding makes sense to me as a computation. (What's the output given an input fuse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the problem here is looking a for a highly specific definition of a very general concept. I don't see the problem of viewing virtually everything as a computation. Although we don't think about it, everything we do is expressible in terms of the Physics of the component parts, down to at least quarks buzzing about. We have the same situation with computation. There's inputs, outputs and a process (all of which could be trivial). Whether they're *interesting* or *useful* as computations or models of computation is a very different question.

The strongest working definition we have comes via the (strong) Church-Turing Thesis, which states that every possible *physically realizable* model of computation is no more powerful than a Turing Machine. If you believe that this is true, then although we may have lots of way to express things, ultimately we can reduce every computation to a Turing Machine, hence giving a *definition* of computation as "anything we can reduce to a Turing Machine".

In this model, the exploding bomb is a computation. It's not a widely applicable one (we hope ;) ), but we can model in some fashion with a Turing Machine (though there is an argument here about the nature of the output and the equivalence with the TM's output). It's also not a good model of computation in general, in that it seems unlikely that the exploding bomb model is Turing complete.

Comment: Rather off-topic, but I bet the exploding bomb model is Turing complete! Explosions could set off other explosions, which could be used to propagate signals and make or-gates. Bomb b could be set to explode at a given time via a device, but a nearby bomb could disable the device while not causing b to explode, which allows for not-gates.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k like domino gates? I don't think that will be turing complete because you can't loop indefinitely as the "computation" will always stop based on the size of the machine/minefield

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not unless the bombs' remains are made into new bombs via nanobots in them and then repositioned...

Answer (score 6):

This is the question that Turing set out to solve in his famous 1936 paper, [On computable numbers, with an application to the Entscheidungsproblem](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf), a paper in which he comes up with (what came to be known as) the Turing machine model. See in particular Section 9.

Turing's work is in the context of computable *numbers*. There are other notions of computation appropriate for computing other kinds of structures, and their study forms part of computation theory (also known as recursion theory).

The main difference between the common notion of computation and your example (an exploding bomb) is the thing being computed. What is being computed by your exploding bomb? Another difference is the computational means, but one can envision a mechanical contraption which uses bombs to compute something more legitimate.

Another point is whether the classical notions of computation apply to what we perceive today as computation – namely, two-way interaction between the computer and the user. This is a common criticism levelled against the classical notional of computability, though interaction can be modelled using the tools of computation theory (it's just not what you learn in class).

Comment: Of course an explosion is a computation. It "computes" exactly the unitary transformation that describes explosion. BTW, many time the physicists I met were "upset" when you say that (say) some quantum gate computes a unitary, rather than evolve it, or transform the physical system accordingly ("*does the gate take a pen and paper and compute the unitary*"?)    :)

Comment: I read section nine of "On computable numbers, with an application to the Entscheidungsproblem," but it didn't really seem to help. Though I didn't read it extremely thoroughly, it seemed to be laying the groundwork for Turing machines. Are you saying that computation is anything that can be modeled as an action done by a Turing machine? If so, wouldn't almost everything be a computation? For example, bombs explosions could be modeled as a Turing machine such that the positions, velocity, and types of the quantum particles of the surrounding particles are encoded as binary.

Comment: "What is being computed by your exploding bomb?" The change in the states of the particles surrounding the bomb according to the laws of physics are being computed.

Comment: "Another point is whether the classical notions of computation apply to what we perceive today as computation – namely, two-way interaction between the computer and the user." I don't think this is quite what is considered computation. Autonomous robots are thought of as doing computations, even though they need not interact with users.

Comment: Here's an idea: computing is the process of generating outputs in order to aid in inference done by optimizers (e.g. people and robots). How's that?

Comment: Obviously you and I have rather different concepts of computation. Mine is "calculation by mechanical means", a vague concept which was made precise by Turing. Yours is different, and more general. Since computation means different things to different people, perhaps you can clarify your concept of computation. Note that a dictionary definition is here completely superfluous; meaning doesn't come from the dictionary, it comes from the speakers and from usage.

Answer (score 3):

On it's most basic level, a computation is just a **mapping** between some set $A$ to some set $B$. every $x\in A$ is called *an input* and the computation maps this input to some output $y\in B$. The mapping needs to be defined on its entire domain: if some input $x\in A$ is not mapped by the computation, then the computation on $x$ is not defined.<sup>(1)</sup>

The other great answers in this thread try to plot the connection between this mapping and the method of achieving it. That is, they explain that to "compute" the output of some input $x$, we need a systematic, well defined method that takes us from an input $x$ to its output $y$. While true, this is not necessary to define computation. Indeed, if you encounter a Genie, and every time you give them a number $x$ they answer with $y$, then they compute something (even if this mapping is not recursive, and no computer can produce it).

In this very broad way to see computation, any physical device is a computer: it transfers the physical system at time $t=0$ (its input) to a different system at time $t=1$ (the output). Moreover, this computation is well defined (i.e., can be specified in a compact way, e.g., by unitary matrices). If you design the device properly, it can perform almost any (recursive) computation you desire. (Scott Aaronson talks quite a bit about "Can Nature compute problems", although his focus is mainly on NP-complete problems, this is very relevant to this discussion).

Bottom line: any mapping defines a computation. Any "device" that transforms an input to the corresponding output, performs ("computes") that specific computation.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> we can extend the discussion to these types of computations, which will make sense when you think on funcitons which are not recursive, but I prefer not to go there.

Comment: The problem with this definition is that it doesn't correspond to how the word "computation" is actually used. PCs are thought of as doing computations, while, say, explosives are not.

Comment: IMHO a mapping is exactly what a computation is not. I think you
confuse syntax and semantics. Clearly you understand mapping as an
input-output relation, however defined. By all my books, that is
semantics. The computation is the means used to actually get the
output corresponding to some input through a sequence of steps. While
you might say that any computation defines a mapping (if only a
syntactic one), I think it is wrong to consider that a mapping defines
a computation, unless you carefully explain that you are going into
hypercomputing which seems a bit beyond the question.

Comment: I should clarify the spirit of my answer (I realize it is not worded that way): the mapping itself is not a computation. The *process* of converting an input into an output is a computation of that specific mapping (function). What I was trying to convey is that the specific process is relevant, any such process is a computation (even a very abstract one, e.g., an "oracle").

Answer (score 1):

I will not attempt to define what a computation is, which was done
rather well by Luke Mathieson and Yuval Filmus.

However, thinking about an exploding device as a computation lead me
to an important side issue: if the explosion is a computation, then
what does it compute? Other than a representation of the device after
it has exploded.

What I am aiming at is that we can define fairly precisely what we
consider to be a computation, and even what can be seen (contrived?)
as one. **We can describe a computation. But can we tell what it is
computing?**

Computation, as commonly defined, is a purely syntactic game. It is a
game of physical structures that are being transformed according to
precise rules. Since our only tool (up to standard transformations)
for representing physical structures is ultimately the string of
symbols, computation ends up being defined as some kind of
formal transformations on strings of symbols. This is true of Turing
Machines, lambda-calculus, partial recursive functions, and other less
popular models. The word calculus (as in lambda-calculus) actually
reflects this view as, in Latin, calculi are small stones used for
representation.

But what this does not tell is what meaning is to be attached to this
syntax, what it represents. Here is what little I think I understand,
as I am not a specialist of such issues (so double check me). The
problem is covered by [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory).

Given a formal system of representations, possibly associated with a
logic (axioms and inference rules) or a computation system
(transformation rules), a model of the formal theory is a mathematical
stucture with components that follow these rules.

The same computation, or more precisely the same description of a
computation can actually have many models corresponding to very
different entities.

For example, a GCD algorithm describe a computation. But  it may be
interpreted on natural numbers, or on polynomials.

This is remindful of [Bertrand Russell'quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell):

> Mathematics may be defined as the subject in which we never know
>     what we are talking about, nor whether what we are saying is true.

The situation is pretty much the same for computation. It is a formal
game, where the moves can be understood in many different ways. But
there are actually deep ties between Mathematics formally defined by
axiomatic systems and Computation Theory.

Computation, algorithmics, was defined to solve mathematical
problems, and many of the modern concepts were thought of by logicians
who were trying to understand the mechanisms that allow us to prove
theorems, starting from axioms and applying inference rules.

Hence, to come back to the exploding device, it can certainly be
construed as a manipulation of a representation, i.e. as a
calculation. But it is generally pretty hard to associate to it any
meaning other than itself.

However, this is not always true, or was not. The principle of [analog
computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) relies on the idea that different representation system
can be used for calculations that are related in some precise
way. Then we can calculate with one system to have an idea of what the
other sytem (too unwieldy to actually use, for example a universe :)
would calculate in the corresponding setting.